# Does GCC 4.2.x Create Constructors?

Tags: c++, gcc, constructor, g++

As a student this past year, I worked with GCC 4.4.7 for compiling C++ code, and it would create constructors and destructors for my classes if they weren't explicitly defined in-code. Is this a feature that exists in version 4.2.x?

Before you ask, yes, I've googled this and looked at gcc.gnu.org but my searches turned up nothing.

Comment: It's a feature not of the compiler, but of the language C++. Read e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Implicitly-declared_default_constructor) to learn when an *implicit constructor* is generated.

Comment: If you do not specify a constructor or destructor, It creates an empty one that does nothing essentially

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The constructor generated isn't implicit. The declarations and definitions are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no user generated constructor/destructor then one will be provided for you.

C++11 standard § 12.1.4(constructor)

> A default constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X that can be called without an argument. If
>   there is no user-declared constructor for class X, a constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared
>   as defaulted (8.4). An implicitly-declared default constructor is an inline public member of its class.

C++11 standard § 12.4.4(destructor)

> If a class has no user-declared destructor, a destructor is implicitly declared as defaulted (8.4). An implicitlydeclared
>   destructor is an inline public member of its class.